# Javascript JSON parsing error: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Tags: javascript, json

I'm not able to parse below string as JSON array:

```
var timeSlots = "['11AM-12PM', '1PM-2PM']";

JSON.parse(timeSlots);
```

Throws the following error:

> VM163:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: in JSON all Strings use double quotes `"` single quotes are not valid

Comment: `JSON.parse('["11AM-12PM", "1PM-2PM"]')`

Comment: `var timeSlots = '"[\'11AM-12PM\', \'1PM-2PM\']"';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, Got the solution

```
var timeSlots = "['11AM-12PM', '1PM-2PM']";
timeSlots.replace(/'/g, '"');
console.log(JSON.parse(timeSlots));
```

Answer (score 4):

In JSON, A name/value pair consists of a field name (in **double** quotes), followed by a colon, followed by a value.

Replace the single quotes with double quotes prefixing the escape (`\`) character:

```js
var timeSlots = "[\"11AM-12PM\", \"1PM-2PM\"]";

console.log(JSON.parse(timeSlots));
```

**OR:** You can simply wrap the string with single quotes which will not require to escape the double quotes:

```js
var timeSlots = '["11AM-12PM", "1PM-2PM"]';

console.log(JSON.parse(timeSlots));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these

```
var timeSlots = "[\"11AM-12PM\", \"1PM-2PM\"]";
```

or

```
var timeSlots = '["11AM-12PM", "1PM-2PM"]';
```